# Why is WMIC giving me Invalid query when trying to uninstall?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, wmic

I'm trying to uninstall regular programs via PowerShell, and everything I've tried to put in the `name="program name"` section, appears to fail.

I've followed [this guide here](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/six-ways-removeuninstall-windows-programs-and-apps) on how to do it.

I've tried removing Google Chrome as my test example. It's not actually want I want to remove, just a test target that I can easily and quickly reinstall.

I did first test on another machine which had Google Chrome, but didn't show up in this list. It also had this error. But now I tested on my main machine, where Google Chrome does show up in the list.

```bsh
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wmic product get name                                                                           Name
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x86 Redistributable - 10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)
Google Chrome
Google Update Helper
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wmic product where name="Google Chrome" call uninstall
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query
```

Some irrelevant `product get name` entries have been removed to keep the list short.

I expect WMIC to uninstall the program, but instead I get the error found above.

Comment: Have you looked into an —uninstall switch from chrome.exe? Other .exe’s probably have one as well.

Comment: I will do this if I have to, but Chrome is both not my real target (real target is some HP bloatware), as well as even if it was part of my real target, it wouldn't be the only one. The problem with going directly for chrome.exe is I'd need to have a directory listed for each program.

Answer (score 1):

The WMIC command requires the filter within quotes: `wmic product where "name='Google Chrome'"`

Powershell also exposes the Get-WMIObject cmdlet (alias `gwmi`) that has cleaner syntax:

```
$chrome = gwmi win32_product -filter "name='Google Chrome'"
$chrome.Uninstall
```

Comment: Tested your exact code (copy-pasted, no typos), and doesn't appear to do anything. No output, no errors, and Chrome is still installed. Does this have some preference for msis like js2010's does?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the package commands too.

```
get-package *chrome* | uninstall-package -whatif
```

Comment: At first I thought this was perfect and hit accept answer too quickly, lol. But sadly this doesn't seem to work. At least it's not missing entries like WMIC is. It successfully finds the chrome package, and with -whatif it does detect chrome and its version, but after removing -whatif, it doesn't actually uninstall chrome.

Comment: Yeah I've tried several programs now, including VLC, Notepad++ and 7-zip. None of them uninstalled, they're all still present, show up in the `get-packge` list when re-run, and can be launched.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
wmic product where "name like 'Google Chrome'" call uninstall

use '' on program name and "" on name
```